# Wordpress Custom database table with DataTable server side processing

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, datatable

I have followed [this toturial](https://itsmereal.com/datatables-server-side-processing-in-wordpress/) and have managed to create a shortcode that shows the datatable with filter option. This table works with the native post type of wordpress.

I need the same datatable but it should get the data from a custom database table i have added `wp_lubuvna_subscribers`

Custom Table:
[image]

So i need to change following function to get data from the above mentioned custom table instead custom post type

```
function datatables_server_side_callback_subscriber_db() {
 
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
 
    $request= $_GET;
 
    $columns = array(
        0   => 'post_title',
        3   => LUBUVNA_PREFIX.'email',
        1   => LUBUVNA_PREFIX.'first_name',
        2   => LUBUVNA_PREFIX.'last_name',
        4   => LUBUVNA_PREFIX.'phone'
        
    );
 
 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'lubuvna_subscriber',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => $request['length'],
        'offset' => $request['start'],
        'order' => $request['order'][0]['dir'],
    );
 
    if ($request['order'][0]['column'] == 0) {
 
        $args['orderby'] = $columns[$request['order'][0]['column']];
 
    } elseif ($request['order'][0]['column'] == 1 || $request['order'][0]['column'] == 2) {
 
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
 
        $args['meta_key'] = $columns[$request['order'][0]['column']];
    }
 
    //$request['search']['value'] <= Value from search
 
    if( !empty($request['search']['value']) ) { // When datatables search is used
        $args['meta_query'] = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'd_title',
                'value' => sanitize_text_field($request['search']['value']),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => LUBUVNA_PREFIX.'email',
                'value' => sanitize_text_field($request['search']['value']),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => LUBUVNA_PREFIX.'first_name',
                'value' => sanitize_text_field($request['search']['value']),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => LUBUVNA_PREFIX.'last_name',
                'value' => sanitize_text_field($request['search']['value']),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => LUBUVNA_PREFIX.'phone',
                'value' => sanitize_text_field($request['search']['value']),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
        );
    }
        
    $subscriber_query = new WP_Query($args);
    $totalData = $subscriber_query->found_posts;
 
    if ( $subscriber_query->have_posts() ) {
        
        while ( $subscriber_query->have_posts() ) {
         
            $subscriber_query->the_post();
 
            $nestedData = array();
            $nestedData[] = get_field(LUBUVNA_PREFIX.'first_name'). '&nbsp'. get_field(LUBUVNA_PREFIX.'last_name');
            $nestedData[] = "<a data-val='".get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() )."' href='".get_permalink()."' data-posttype='".get_post_type( get_the_ID() )."' class='generallink'>" . get_field(LUBUVNA_PREFIX.'email') . "</a>";
            $nestedData[] = get_field(LUBUVNA_PREFIX.'first_name');
            $nestedData[] = get_field(LUBUVNA_PREFIX.'last_name');
            $nestedData[] = get_field(LUBUVNA_PREFIX.'phone');
 
            $data[] = $nestedData;
 
        }
 
        wp_reset_query();
 
        $json_data = array(
            "draw" => intval($request['draw']),
            "recordsTotal" => intval($totalData),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalData),
            "data" => $data
        );
 
        echo json_encode($json_data);
 
    } else {
 
        $json_data = array(
            "data" => array()
        );
 
        echo json_encode($json_data);
    }
     
    wp_die();
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i will post this here, in case someone else is looking for the same solution. I had to add `global $wpdb`and get the data from my custom database table. it works perfectly with paging / sorting / Search.

```
function datatables_server_side_callback_subscriber_db() {
 
    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    global $wpdb;

    // Table name
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "lubuvna_subscribers";

    // Request
    $request= $_GET;

    // Columns
    $columns = array(
        0   => 'ID',
        1   => 'first_name',
        2   => 'last_name',
        3   => 'email',
        4   => 'phone'
        
    );

    // Datatable Filters
    $column = $columns[$request['order'][0]['column']];
    $offset = $request['start'];
    $length = $request['length'];
    $order = $request['order'][0]['dir'];
    
    // Search all columns
    $sql_where = "";
    if ( !empty($request['search']['value']) ) {

        $sql_where .= "WHERE ";

        foreach ($columns as $column) {

             $sql_where .= $column . " LIKE '%" . sanitize_text_field($request['search']['value']) . "%' OR ";

        }

        $sql_where = substr($sql_where, 0, -3);
    }

    // Total Records in the datatable
    $total_table_records = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM {$table_name}";
    $total_fetched_records = $wpdb->get_results($total_table_records, OBJECT);
    $total_records = $total_fetched_records[0]->count;

    // Total Records Search
    $total_table_records_search = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM $table_name $sql_where";
    $total_fetched_records_search = $wpdb->get_results($total_table_records_search, OBJECT);
    $total_records_search = $total_fetched_records_search[0]->count;

    // Query
    $total_results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name $sql_where ORDER BY $column $order LIMIT $offset, $length" );

    if ( !empty($total_results) ) {
        foreach ($total_results as $row){
            $nestedData = array();
            $nestedData[] = $row->ID;
            $nestedData[] = $row->first_name;
            $nestedData[] = $row->last_name;
            $nestedData[] = $row->email;
            $nestedData[] = $row->phone;
            $data[] = $nestedData;
        }

        $json_data = array(
            "draw" => intval($request['draw']),
            "recordsTotal" => intval($total_records),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval($total_records_search),
            "data" => $data
        );
    
        echo json_encode($json_data);

    } else {

        $json_data = array(
            "data" => array()
        );
 
        echo json_encode($json_data);

    }
    
    wp_die();
 
}
```